# Getting data from World Bank API using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I'm trying to obtain a table of data obtaining just the country, year and value from this World Bank API but I can't seem to filter for just the data I want. I've seen that these types of questions have already been asked but all the answers didn't seem to work.

Would really appreciate some help. Thank you!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
```

```
url ="http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/{}/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD?date=2015&format=json"
country = ["DZA","AGO","ARG","AUS","AUT","BEL","BRA","CAN","CHL","CHN","COL","CYP", "CZE","DNK","FIN","FRA","GEO","DEU",
          "GRC""HUN","ISL","IND","IDN","IRL","ISR","ITA","JPN","KAZ","KWT","LBN","LIE","MYS","MEX","MCO","MAR","NPL","NLD",
          "NZL","NGA","NOR","OMN","PER","PHL","POL","PRT","QAT","ROU","SGP","ZAF","ESP","SWE","CHE","TZA","THA","TUR","UKR",
          "GBR","USA","VNM","ZWE"]

html={}
for i in country:
 url_one = url.format(i)
 html[i] = requests.get(url_one).json()
```

```
my_values=[]
for i in country:

  value=html[i][1][0]['value']
  my_values.append(value)
```

**Edit**

My data currently looks like this, I'm trying to extract the country name which is in '{'country': {'id': 'AO', 'value': 'Angola''}, the 'date' and the 'value'
[image: data]

**Edit 2**
Got the data I'm looking for but its repeated twice each
[image: repeated data]

Comment: Pandas already has bultin tool to read json files, `pandas.read_json("your_url")`

Comment: Hmm no that didn't seem to work. I added the message that came up to the initial question

Comment: You are currently getting a list, try to open the link and see what exactly you want, then extract the desired dictionary with list slicing

Comment: @AkmalSoliev ah yes I understand that but i'm having trouble extracting what I need because the data is nested in many arrays

Comment: I see you found your answer, one quick and dirty way right now is just to remove duplicates

Comment: Just to clairify your question - Could you provide some more details, what you exactly expect to get, cause there are slight deviations between  your request and your edits. do you only want to retriev information for one or all years, ...? Would be great and improve your question, so everybody could reproduce your issue and get the goal. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** *Assumed that it would be great to store information for all the years at once and not only for one year - Enables you to simply filter in later processing. Take a look, there is a missing "," between your countries `"GRC""HUN"`*

There are different options to achieve your goal, just point with two of them in the right direction.

##### Option #1

Pick information needed from json response, create a reshaped dict and `append()` it to `my_values`:

```
for d in data[1]:

    my_values.append({
        'country':d['country']['value'],
        'date':d['date'],
        'value':d['value']
    })
```

#### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/%s/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD?format=json'
countries = ["DZA","AGO","ARG","AUS","AUT","BEL","BRA","CAN","CHL","CHN","COL","CYP", "CZE","DNK","FIN","FRA","GEO","DEU",
          "GRC","HUN","ISL","IND","IDN","IRL","ISR","ITA","JPN","KAZ","KWT","LBN","LIE","MYS","MEX","MCO","MAR","NPL","NLD",
          "NZL","NGA","NOR","OMN","PER","PHL","POL","PRT","QAT","ROU","SGP","ZAF","ESP","SWE","CHE","TZA","THA","TUR","UKR",
          "GBR","USA","VNM","ZWE"]
    
my_values = []
for country in countries:
    data = requests.get(url %country).json()

    try:
        for d in data[1]:
            my_values.append({
                'country':d['country']['value'],
                'date':d['date'],
                'value':d['value']
            })
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'[ERROR] country ==> {country} error ==> {err}')

pd.DataFrame(my_values).sort_values(['country', 'date'], ascending=True)
```

##### Option #2

Create a dataframes directly from the json response, concat them and make some adjustments on the final dataframe:

```
for d in data[1]:
    my_values.append(pd.DataFrame(d))

...

pd.concat(my_values).loc[['value']][['country','date','value']].sort_values(['country', 'date'], ascending=True)
```

#### Output

| country | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Algeria | 1971 | 341.389 |
| Algeria | 1972 | 442.678 |
| Algeria | 1973 | 554.293 |
| Algeria | 1974 | 818.008 |
| Algeria | 1975 | 936.79 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Zimbabwe | 2016 | 1464.59 |
| Zimbabwe | 2017 | 1235.19 |
| Zimbabwe | 2018 | 1254.64 |
| Zimbabwe | 2019 | 1316.74 |
| Zimbabwe | 2020 | 1214.51 |

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much! (for pointing out the missing '' as well. And yes- I was looking for all years, not just one year. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `read_json` method needs valid JSON str, path object or file-like object, but you put string.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Try this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/%s/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD?date=2015&format=json"
countries = ["DZA","AGO","ARG","AUS","AUT","BEL","BRA","CAN","CHL","CHN","COL","CYP", "CZE","DNK","FIN","FRA","GEO","DEU",
          "GRC""HUN","ISL","IND","IDN","IRL","ISR","ITA","JPN","KAZ","KWT","LBN","LIE","MYS","MEX","MCO","MAR","NPL","NLD",
          "NZL","NGA","NOR","OMN","PER","PHL","POL","PRT","QAT","ROU","SGP","ZAF","ESP","SWE","CHE","TZA","THA","TUR","UKR",
          "GBR","USA","VNM","ZWE"]

datas = []
for country in countries:
    data = requests.get(url %country).json()
    try:
        values = data[1][0]
        datas.append(pd.DataFrame(values))
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"[ERROR] country ==> {country} with error ==> {err}")

df = pd.concat(datas)
```

Comment: hm im still getting an error message, is there a typo in `for country in countrys:`

Comment: @Jadewest and now

Comment: It's working now. Thanks so much! but the same item seems to be appearing twice, once as the country name and once as the country code (see the screenshot added in question under Edit 2)- any idea how to fix that?